# Some numbers are automatically formatted using rich.console, how to prevent this?

Tags: python, rich

The following code

```
from rich.console import Console

console = Console()

console.print("ciao-16S-123")
```

will print the number 123 highlighted (in blue, in my terminal).
This happens on many strings with numbers, what could be the problem
that causes this unwanted formatting, and how to prevent it?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per `Rich` [documentation](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/highlighting.html), *"Rich can apply styles to patterns in text which you print() or log(). With the default settings, Rich will highlight things such as numbers, strings, collections, booleans, None, and a few more exotic patterns such as file paths, URLs and UUIDs."*

You can disable it like this:

```py
console.print("ciao-16S-123", highlight=False)
```

You can also define a [custom highlighter](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/highlighting.html#custom-highlighters) better suited for your needs.